# how do I rendering multiple components using xstreamjs

Tags: reactive-programming, cyclejs, xstream-js

Suppose, I want to render 3 buttons which are mapped from Array

```
export const homePage = soruces => {
  const array$ = xs.fromArray([1,2,3])
  return {
    DOM: array$.map(e => {
                  return <button id={e}>click</button>
                })
  };
};
```

but I only get the lastest button which has id of 3

```
<div id="app">
   <button id="3">click</button>
</div>
```

how do i get all the buttons rendered like this using xstream or rxjs

```
<div id="app">
  <button id="1">click</button>
  <button id="2">click</button>
  <button id="3">click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends a bit on what you want to achieve. The code you have there basically says: "I get three pieces of data, each at some arbitrary point of time" (because `fromArray` basically takes the data from the array one by one and puts it into the stream.
If you now what to collect the data over time, you can add `fold((buttons, newButton) => buttons.concat(newButton), [])`.

If however you just happen to have three poeces of data, that always should be three buttons, do not use `fromArray` but the normal `Array.map`. You can then use `xs.of` to emit the three buttons **at once** (compared to one by one in the first part)